# BigTable CheckAndPut CompareOp.Greater always Puts

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

The checkAndPut method appears to always Put the value regardless of the GREATER compareOp.  The code below illustrates this issue since the value "a" is lexicographically smaller than "bbbbbb", one would expect that a CheckAndPut would not put in the scenario, however it does.

I am using

```
<groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
<artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
```

Below is the code:

```
        byte[] key = "key17".getBytes();
        byte[] smaller = "a".getBytes();
        byte[] larger = "bbbbbb".getBytes();
        byte[] COL_FAMILY = "family".getBytes();
        byte[] COL_QUAL = "qual".getBytes();

        /** if null, we set it here **/
        boolean doRun = table.checkAndPut(key, COL_FAMILY, COL_QUAL, null,
                new Put(key).addColumn(COL_FAMILY, COL_QUAL, smaller));
        System.out.println("WRITE OCCURRED: " + doRun);

        Result rr = table.get(new Get(key).addFamily(COL_FAMILY));
        byte[] res = rr.getValue(COL_FAMILY, COL_QUAL);
        System.out.println("BEFORE STORED VAL: " + new String(res));

        // should NOT put and return false since "a" is NOT greater than
        // "bbbbbb"
        doRun = table.checkAndPut(key, COL_FAMILY, COL_QUAL, CompareOp.GREATER, larger,
                new Put(key).addColumn(COL_FAMILY, COL_QUAL, larger));

        rr = table.get(new Get(key).addFamily(COL_FAMILY));
        res = rr.getValue(COL_FAMILY, COL_QUAL);
        System.out.println("AFTER STORED VAL: " + new String(res));
        System.out.println("WRITE OCCURRED: " + doRun);
```

Output

```
WRITE OCCURRED: true
BEFORE STORED VAL: a
AFTER STORED VAL: bbbbbb
WRITE OCCURRED: true
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking the HBASE docs, the example provided clarified what was actually being compared

```
GREATER operator means expected value > existing <=> add the put.
```

I had interpreted the opposite, so there is no issue.